# How to read JSON String attribute into custom class object using Gson?

Tags: java, json, string, gson

When reading a JSON :

```
{"field":"value"}
```

into a String field :

```
public class Test {
    private String field;
}
```

using `Gson.fromJson` it works as intended and the member String field gets the value "value".

My question is, is there a way to read the same JSON into a custom class so that the custom class object can be constructed with the String value? e.g.

```
public class Test {
    private MyField<String> field;
}

public class MyField<T> {
    private T value;
    public MyField(T v) {
        value = v;
    }
}
```

The reason being the String class is final and cannot be extended, yet I don't want the JSON to be changed into this :

```
{"field":{"value":"value"}}
```

If there is a way to extend the String class, it is the best. Otherwise, will need a way for Gson to read string into a custom class that can be constructed by string. Something to do with writing a custom `TypeAdapter`?

Comment: Funny how this community just neg without saying anything...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use custom `JsonDeserializer`, `JsonSerializer`. Here is simple demo version:

```
static class MyFieldAsValueTypeAdapter<T> implements
        JsonDeserializer<MyField<T>>, JsonSerializer<MyField<T>> {
    private Gson gson = new Gson();
    @Override
    public MyField<T> deserialize(JsonElement json, Type typeOfT,
                                  JsonDeserializationContext context)
            throws JsonParseException {
        JsonObject obj = new JsonObject();
        obj.add("value", json);
        return gson.fromJson(obj, typeOfT);
    }

    @Override
    public JsonElement serialize(MyField<T> src, Type typeOfSrc,
                                 JsonSerializationContext context) {
        return context.serialize(src.getValue());
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    GsonBuilder b = new GsonBuilder();
    b.registerTypeAdapter(MyField.class , new MyFieldAsValueTypeAdapter());
    Gson gson = b.create();

    String json = "{\"field\":\"value1\"}";
    Test test = gson.fromJson(json, Test.class);
}
```

Be careful with internal `Gson gson = new Gson()`. If you have some other setup, you will need to register it on internal version or pass default MyField deserializer/serializer to your custom implementation.